# IOS не получаю первую push нотификацию в background

Tags: ios, push-уведомления

IOS 13.7 IPhone Xr, Xcode Version 11.7 (11E801a)

Я изменил схему приложения и установил launch mode в значение "Wait for the executable to be launched".
Потом запускаю приложение и отправляю нотификацию на моё устройство

Нотификация выглядит так:

```
{
"aps":{
    "content-available":1
      }
}
```

В xcode статус приложения меняется с  "Waiting to attach to test on iPhone" на "Running test on iPhone", но нотификация не была получена.

Я пытаюсь поймать нотификацию в этом методе:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

Следующую нотификацию я успешно получаю. Ситуация воспроизводиться после перезапуска приложения.

Мне нужна помощь в получении первой нотификации в фоне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если приложение не запущенно, то при получении нотификации вызовется метод `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` с нотификацией в параметре `launchOptions`

```
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        ...
        let notificationOption = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification]
        if let notification = notificationOption as? [String:AnyObject]{
           // received notification
        }
        ...
    }
```